# Is there a way to reference the class of the current object

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance

I'm making a class which has a method that launches some threads of member functions in the same class. I'm quite new to threads in c++, especially when classes are involved but this is what iv'e come up with.

```
class A
{
public:
    void StartThreads()
    {
        std::thread fooThread(&A::FooFunc, this);
        fooThread.join();
    }
protected:
    virtual void FooFunc()
    {
        while (true)
            std::cout << "hello\n";
    }
};
```

My question is, if i can get the name of the current object, because now if i create a class B which inherits from A but overwrites FooFunc, FooFunc from class A will be called when i do:

```
B b;
b.StartThreads();
```

So i'm looking for a way to replace `std::thread fooThread(&A::FooFunc, this)` with something like `std::thread fooThread(&this->GetClass()::FooFunc, this)`. I could just make `StartThreads` virtual and overwrite it in derived classes, but It would be better just to write it once and being done with it. Is there a way to do this or something that results in the same thing?

Comment: Doesnt this code do what you want already? [it calls the derived one if you call StartThreads on a derived class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b926ca1649ddab0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers, it turned out that my question was unrelated and that i messed up some other members in the class.

Thanks for your answers giving me some insight into other ways you can do the same thing using different methods. (https://stackoverflow.com/users/9335240/user9335240)

Answer (score 0):

In case of that your `this` is known at compile-time then static metaprogramming to the rescue.

C++, Swift and Rust (and now Scala also) are static languages that has a lot of compile time tricks to do for problems like that.

How? In your case *templates* could help you.

Also, you don't need it to be a member function, it can be a friend function (so that you can easily use templates).

```
class A
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    friend void StartThreads(const T& obj);
protected:
    virtual void FooFunc()
    {
        while (true)
            std::cout << "hello\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
void StartThreads(const T& obj) {
    std::thread fooThread(&T::FooFunc, obj);
    fooThread.join();
}
```

***WARNING:*** This *ONLY* works if the class is known at compile time, i.e.

```
class B: public A {
};

...

B b;
A &a = b;
StartThreads(a);  // Will call it AS IF IT IS A, NOT B
```

---

Another solution:

Functional programming to the rescue, you can use lambdas (or functors using structs if you are on C++ prior to C++11)

- C++11:

  ```
  void StartThreads()
  {
      std::thread fooThread([=](){ this->FooFunc(); });
      fooThread.join();
  }
  ```
- C++98:

  ```
  // Forward declaration     
  class A;

  // The functor class (the functor is an object that is callable (i.e. has the operator (), which is the call operator overloaded))
  struct ThreadContainer {
  private:
      A &f;
  public:
      ThreadContainer(A &f): f(f) {}
      void operator() ();
  };

  class A
  {
  public:
      // To allow access of the protected FooFunc function
      friend void ThreadContainer::operator() ();

      void StartThreads()
      {
          // Create the functor
          ThreadContainer a(*this);
          // Start the thread with the "call" operator, the implementation of the constructor tries to "call" the operand, which here is a
          std::thread fooThread(a);
          fooThread.join();
      }
  protected:
      virtual void FooFunc()
      {
          while (true)
              std::cout << "hello\n";
      }
  };

  class B: public A {
      protected:
      virtual void FooFunc() {
          while(true)
              std::cout << "overridden\n";
      }
  };

  void ThreadContainer::operator() () {
      f.FooFunc();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You've looked at using a virtual `FooFunc()` directly, and somehow surmised that it doesn't work. (I won't address the accuracy of that here, as that is being brought up in the question's comments.) You don't like the idea of moving the virtual function earlier in the process. So why not move it later? There is a somewhat-common paradigm out there that uses non-virtual wrappers to virtual functions. (Usually the wrapper is public while the virtual function is protected or private.) So, something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    void StartThreads()
    {
        std::thread fooThread(&A::FooFuncCaller, this); // <-- call the new function
        fooThread.join();
    }
protected:
    void FooFuncCaller()  // <-- new function layer
    {
        FooFunc();
    }
    virtual void FooFunc()
    {
        while (true)
            std::cout << "hello\n";
    }
};
```

Of course, if the direct call to the virtual `Foofunc` works, might as well use that. Still, this is simpler than using templates or custom functor classes. A lambda is a reasonable alternative, with the benefit of not changing your class' interface (header file).